# why my ObservedObject is updated but not showing its updated content in the View

Tags: swift, timer, observableobject, observedobject

I trying to show a simple View of counting down the time using ObservableObject but it seems my ObservedObject is updated but not showing its updated content to its binded view. The display stay at 60

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class myTimer: ObservableObject {

    @Published var timeRemaining = 60
    var timer: Timer?

    init() {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector (countDownTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    @objc func countDownTime () {
        if (timeRemaining < 60) {
            timeRemaining -= 1
        }
    }

    func resetCount () {
        timeRemaining = 60
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var myTimeCount: myTimer = myTimer()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack {
                Text("Time remaining \(myTimeCount.timeRemaining)")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .padding()

                Button(action: resetCount) {
                    Text("Reset Counter")
                }
            }

        }

    }
    func resetCount() {
        myTimeCount.resetCount()
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTsIO.png)

Comment: solved. my fault of wrong check if statement

Answer (score 0):

You can also change your init slightly and get rid of `@objc func countDownTime ()` at all

```swift
    init() {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { [weak self] _ in
            self?.timeRemaining -= 1
        }
    }
```